# FlatList stop scroll when button press during scroll

Tags: react-native, scrollview

i would like to know if there is any way to stop scroll event on iOs and Android

Steps to reproduce

1. scroll FlatList / ScrollView
2. click any button

already tried "onScroll" but when i set scroll ref.scrollTo it will scroll when stroll stops

Example GIF:
[image]

Answer (score 0):

This is just an idea which I think might work, you may have to test it yourself.

Assuming you have the following state, controlling the modal.

```
const [open, setOpen] = useState(false);
```

You can probably add a onScroll event to Flatlist (onScroll is inherited from ScrollView), then

```
   const onScroll = (e) => {
      if (open) e.preventDefault();
   }
```

If there is a delay before e.preventDefault is called, since setting state is async, you may want to use useRef() instead of useState() for checking `if (open)` since scroll happens quickly.

Another idea is to probably use a listener for the flat list, to listen to scroll, using same logic above.

Comment: tryed this and it doesnt work 

```if (event.nativeEvent.contentOffset.y > 300) {
                        event.stopPropagation();
                    }``` even stopPropagation without IF doesnt work

Comment: Then you can probably try using onScrollBeginDrag to get the offset and onScrollEnd to set the offset. However, since you have mention there is no effect, then probably there isn't a "official" way to handle thins except for hack.

Comment: yea i can set ScrollTo or even set scroll position but after move animation is done, u know any hacks for this ?